# Errors while using 3D CNN in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I am trying to use aa 3D CNN for 3D brain image classification. I have pre-processed images as input.

Currently it´s an experiment on only 8 patients, till I successfully can run the code. Validation-split is 0.1.

```
import os
import glob
import dicom
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.ndimage
import keras
import tensorflow
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution3D, MaxPooling3D, 
ZeroPadding3D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

images_path = '/Users/rahulpaul/Desktop/data/'


def get_3d_data(path):
    slices = [dicom.read_file(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)]
    slices.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.InstanceNumber))
    return np.stack([s.pixel_array for s in slices])

patients = os.listdir(images_path)
patients.sort()

sample_image = get_3d_data(images_path + patients[0])

labels_csv = 
pd.read_csv('/Users/rahulpaul/Desktop/exp/stage1_labels.csv', index_col='id')

# Remove the (single) unlabbeled patient from our list
patients = labels_csv.ix[patients].dropna().index

# And finally get the training labels
train_labels = labels_csv.ix[patients].cancer.astype(np.float16).as_matrix()
train_labels = train_labels.reshape([len(train_labels), 1])

def process_image(path):
    img = get_3d_data(path)
    img[img == -2000] = 0
    img = scipy.ndimage.zoom(img.astype(np.float), 0.25)
    img_std = np.std(img)
    img_avg = np.average(img)
    return np.clip((img - img_avg + img_std) / (img_std * 2), 0, 1).astype(np.float16)


train_features = np.zeros([len(patients), 1, 128, 128, 128], np.float16)
for i in range(len(patients)):
    f = process_image(images_path + patients[i])
    f = np.concatenate([f, np.zeros([128 - f.shape[0], 128, 128], np.float16)]) # Pads the image
    f = f.reshape([1, 128, 128, 128]) # add an extra dimension for the color channel
    train_features[i] = f


nn = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution3D(32, 3, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu', input_shape=train_features.shape[1:], dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.convolutional.MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution3D(32, 3, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu', dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.convolutional.MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution3D(64, 3, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu', dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.convolutional.MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution3D(64, 3, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu', dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.convolutional.MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution3D(128, 3, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu', dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.convolutional.MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution3D(256, 3, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu', dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.convolutional.AveragePooling3D((4, 4, 4), dim_ordering='th'),
        keras.layers.core.Flatten(),
        keras.layers.core.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        keras.layers.core.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
nn.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


nn.fit(train_features, train_labels, batch_size=1,validation_split=0.1, nb_epoch=1)
```

But I am getting an error while running the code. I tried both Tensorflow and Theano backend but I got the same error.

```
Train on 0 samples, validate on 0 samples
Epoch 1/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "third.py", line 84, in <module>
    nn.fit(train_features, train_labels, batch_size=1,validation_split=0.1, nb_epoch=1)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 672, in fit
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1196, in fit
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 911, in _fit_loop
callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 76, in on_epoch_end
callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 265, in on_epoch_end
self.progbar.update(self.seen, self.log_values, force=True)
AttributeError: 'ProgbarLogger' object has no attribute 'log_values'
```

Can anyone please help me with the code?

Comment: What Keras version are you using? Seems the problem is inside Keras' code.

Comment: What is the output of len(train_features) ?

Comment: Can you try to remove the validation split temporarily? The error might be thrown because if you only have 8 samples (as I understood) than a split of 0.1 is less than 1.

Comment: @petezurich i have tried 0.25, 0.5 as validation split. But the error is still coming.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I am using an older version. 1.2.2

Comment: What if you remove the validation split entirely (just to make sure that this definitely doesn´t cause the error)?

Comment: @petezurich i tried that too....by removing validation_split and  only kept the train data... but still same error.

Comment: @petezurich is there any error in my code?

Comment: What I find suspicious is the first line of the error message: `Train on 0 samples, validate on 0 samples`. This indicates that somehow you don´t feed any data into your network which in turn would explain that the Logger throws an error because it doesn´t have anything to log.

Comment: Can you somehow make sure that your `process_image` function actually fetches and returns an image?